# How to build my own class libraries in Arduino application?

Tags: class, arduino, path

**Goal:**
Write varied c++  classes (.cpp + .h) in separate files and make sure they each compile individually before including them into a larger project.

**Platform:** 
 Arduino app 1.8.12 on mac osx catalina.

**Problem**
I can't figure out a clean simple way to do this.

*the obvious thing to do doesn't work:*
The arduino application itself only lets me open .ino files-- thus I can't simply open a .cpp file an then tell it to compile.

I have tried to follow the example tutorial at the arduino website but it seems to be outdated in terms of the menu commands it refers to
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

**I have been trying three workarounds on this**

1. I can put all of the .cpp and .h files in a directory with a .ino file that inludes them.  This directory is in my Sketches folder.  When I do this the whole thing will compile. And so I can try to find errors that way.
2. I can put each class file (.cpp and .h)  in it's own directory, named the same then put this directory in the local adruino library path.  THen I create a dummy sketch that simply includes the header file for the class.  This  seems to start checking my syntax on the header.
3. put everything in a single file and call it .ino.  Yuck in terms of managable code.

The trouble with these besides being kludges is that (1) is sort of an all or none problem with too many classes to have to debug at once.  and (2) is too few classes at once.

Surely there is simply some way to use the Arduino app like a normal compiler, even if it's a command line command, to compile the class and give me the error messages.

???

I apologize for not being an expert yet on using the arduino compiler.  I have in the past managed to set up ATOM as my IDE One time but it's no longer working for me.  I like the Arduio app because the IDE is pretty simple but has everything from library searches to device information and serial monitoring, so I'm reluctant to switch.  But if someone give me a good reccomendation on how to get started with a better IDE i would try it.

Comment: You can edit .cpp and .h files in any text editor.  Notepad++ is popular and a little more towards coding.  But any text editor will do.  Like any other library, it doesn't need to be opened in the IDE in order to be included from a sketch and compiled.

Comment: I like Eclipse pretty well for Arduino stuff.  There are a few different pretty easy ways to get it to work with Arduino.  There are lots of instructions online.

Comment: This is exactly the reasons why I no longer using Arduino IDE. I use [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org), it provide a good project development structure, library dependency management, compiler flags settings, and many more. It is a plugin that you can install on either Atom or VScode editor, take a look at this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIkGTwLOD7o) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBlHNBNHESQ) for a quick start.

Answer (score 1):

In Arduino IDE the main sketch file must be .ino. You can add cpp and h files to the sketch folder in IDE or outside the IDE. They will be opened as tabs in Arduino IDE.

If you want to cpp/h files to be independent, [create a library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) (the tutorial is not outdated). To test the library create a test sketch. The library will be compiled with the sketch. To edit the source files of the library you can't use Arduino IDE.

Note: 'sketch' is 'project', not an ino file. 'sketch' is a folder with the main sketch file and additional .ino, .h, .cpp, .c, .S files.

Comment: One very important detail that is not stated in the tutorial is that if you include  foo.h into an .ino then this triggers the compilation of foo.cpp (if it's found).  This is FAR from obvious. and it's this fact that actually answers the question, not the tutorial.   Also the point where the tutorial is out of date is exactly at the point in the tutorial where is explicitly talks about including the library file.

Comment: @AlexanderHamilton, foo.cpp is always compiled if it is in the sketch folder or in library. this is c++ build process. it first compiles all units, then links them together

Comment: This is a choice by the builder not the compiler and thus is specific to Arduino.app not all C++ bulider programs. This is because the linker will not require the cpp file unless some function in it is actually called from main().  Thus smart builder apps will notice this and not bother to compile the .cpp,and simply include the header file.  This is why I was saying it is not obvious whether the ardunio builder will compile a .cpp file just because the .h was included.

Comment: @AlexanderHamilton, there is no smartness without compiling the units, because before compiling there is no information what is inside them

Comment: Thank you for your explains.  the original question was about how one _restricts_ the compilers attention to just one or a specific set of cpp files. In the build systems I was previously familiar with unless add the file to the build list it isn't built. Arduino seems to build everything it finds by default in any dircectory it follows a .h file to!

Comment: @AlexanderHamilton, this is a convention. there is no makefile. the content of the folder defines the list

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the Arduino app to compile just one .cpp file by itself.  These are quite clumsy in that you have to move or copy the .h and .cpp out of your project folder to *magic* locations.  But it's not too hard either.  The Tutorial at Arduino.cc on making your own libraies muffs explaining these crictical steps cleanly.

Lets say the code to compile is foo.h and foo.cpp

**method #1**

1. make a folder in your local (not system) library folder that is called "foo".  and put foo.h and foo.cpp in this folder.
2. create a dummy project dummy.ino like this:

```
#include "foo.h"  // note the quotes not <angle brackets>
setup (){};
loop (){};
```

3. Compile the dummy project

Here's the magic that happens.  When Arduino.app includes "foo.h" it finds the path in the local library also has foo.cpp  and even though there is no need to compile this (the linker won't ever require it) the build system sees the include of the header and compiles it anyhow.  it's  as a side effect!

So there you go.

(Aside: this also has the reverse side effect that if you ever have a perfectly useful header and accidentally have a similarly named but broken .cpp file on the same file path the ardunio compiler will error when it uselessly and mistakenly compiles a file even though it will never link against it.)

**Alternate method 1:** (slightly better).

1. Create the same  dummy.ino sketch *USING the Arduino app*. Save it.  When you go to save this, *using the ardunio app*, it will courteously offer to make a folder by the same name to place it into.  Accept this kind offer.
2. Place foo.h and foo.cpp in this same folder as dummy.ino.
3. close the arduino app window of the dummy.ino
4. re-open dummy.ino in a new arduino window.  This will open not just dummy.ino but also open tabs for foo.h and foo.cpp
5. compile it.

**Method #2:**  (quick and easy but a bad dev practice)

1. Open a new default sketch in ardunio.app
2. paste the contents of  foo.f at the top, leaving the setup() and loop() declarations alone.
3. paste the contents of foo.cpp *below* that.
4. compile it.

This kludge works to check foo.cpp syntax but it's not checking any of the path resolution process.